# Wordpress Astra Theme with Spectra. Tabs on tabs block moving from top to side, if browser is getting narrower

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, datastax-astra, spectra

I'm using the tabs block from Spectra in the Astra Theme for displaying the results of tournament rounds of my chessclub. These results are just tables, and without the tabs block the page is getting very long in some cases.

I now have the problem, that the tabs, which are configured to show up on the top of the block are moving to the side, if the page is getting resized and narrower.

The tabs block doesn't seem to be a flexbox block, because the according options are missing in the editor.

Target is, that these tabs are staying on top, all the time, regardless of the width of the page. Can anybody help to achieve this?

The page, where the issue is visible is: https://ford-schachfreunde.de/ford-pokal-2024/

I tried to change some CSS-options, but I'm not a web designer/developer, just a hobbyist, who is maintaining the chess clubs site and I don't have a clue (yet) where to start, to solve the problem.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After inspecting there are 2 media break points, 1023px and 767px, where the `flex-direction` of some elements changes from `row` to `column` and the other way around, also the `max-width` of the tab list changes to `24%` and the `max-width` of the table below the tabs changes to `75%`.

To keep story short, lets keep the things like above 1023px by using `!important` for the relevant styles to override everything.

The tricks are:

1. use devtools
2. inspect an element. change width of window.
3. observe and take notes.
4. common properties for layout: flex, width, padding, margin, float... and many more actually.

```css
.uagb-tabs__body-wrap {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

ul.uagb-tabs__panel.uagb-tabs__align-left {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.wp-block-uagb-tabs {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
}
```